# cmake avoid re-build all for test

Tags: unit-testing, cmake

I want to avoid build twice all sources for my test... I have the following project tree:

```
|-- my_executable
  |-- CMakeFiles.txt
  |-- resources
  |-- include
  |-- src
    |-- CMakeFiles.txt
    |-- *.cpp
  |-- test
    |-- CMakeFiles.txt
    |-- test.cpp
```

The problem is that for building test I need the same sources of `my_executable` and `cmake` build them twice.

The build time this way is double.

Can I do better?

**What I have tried:**

Have an `OBJECT` library and then use the `*.obj` files as input of both test and application.

But the problem is that this "objects" library has some dependencies, `cpprestsdk`, `boost` and others... I'm unable to set correctly the include dir for this target library :(

Answer (score 0):

You can add a library target and link both your main executable and test code with that library. That way the library is built once and used many times.